# CSS3 transition in IE11 doesn't work

Tags: css, css-transitions, internet-explorer-11

Why this doesn't work only on IE11? In FF and Chrome it is fine

```
.js-search-item {
  width: 30px;
  padding: 0px; 
  margin: 0px; 

  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tkyzv3na/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery#1.10.0` doesn't appear to work in IE11 within JSFiddle. Bumped to `jQuery#1.11.0`: http://jsfiddle.net/tkyzv3na/3/

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your jQuery version. Problem has nothing to do with the code you're showing. `transition` works fine in IE10+. You don't need `-ms-transition` [ever](http://www.impressivewebs.com/dropping-ms-vendor-prefixes-ie10/).